# Substituindo If/else em Javascript

Tags: javascript, if, condição

Estou criando um formulário que vai possuir vários checkbox:

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input name="mini" id="SistemaRestauracao" class="mini" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <b> Sistemas de Restauração - </b> 8h às 12h e 14h às 18h
      </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input name="mini" id="custoRodoviarios" class="mini" type="checkbox" value="2">
        <b> Custos Rodoviários - </b> 8h às 12h e 14h às 18h
      </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input name="mini" id="questoesAmbientais" class="mini" type="checkbox" value="3">
        <b> Questões ambientais - </b> 8h às 12h
      </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input name="mini" id="sinalizacaoSeguranca" class="mini" type="checkbox" value="4">
        <b> Sinalização e Segurança - </b> 14h às 18h
      </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input name="mini" id="sustentabilidade" class="mini" type="checkbox" value="5">
        <b> Sustentabilidade portuária - </b> 8h às 12h
      </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input name="mini" id="economia" class="mini" type="checkbox" value="6">
        <b> Economia de transporte - </b> 14h às 18h
      </label>
</div>
<br>
<label>Visita Técnica</label>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="visitaManha" value="">
        <b> TRANSPORTE FERROVIARIO E MARÍTIMO - </b> 9h às 12h
      </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="visitaTarde" value="">
        <b> TRANSPORTE FERROVIARIO E MARÍTIMO - </b>14h às 17h
      </label>
</div>
```

Eu preciso criar um sistema de validação onde deve ser desabilitado um checkbox quando o outro de mesmo horario for selecionado. Ex. Selecionei um curso de 08:00 as 12:00 então desabilita os cursos com duração dia todo e os outros de 08:00 as 12:00 e por ai vai...

Eu consigo fazer isso utilizando condição if/else, porém fica gigante com tanto "if". Qual seria outra solução em Javascript/Jquery que eu poderia utilizar para evitar o uso de tantos ifs?

Comment: O jeito mais fácil é representar como objetos essas propriedades. Você coleciona esses objetos todos em um vetor, aí ao selecionar algo no checkbox, passaria para um detetor de mudança de valor o objetos relacionado e, então, percorreria o vetor de checkboxes que estão amarrados aos outros cursos, desmarcando aqueles cujos objetos chocam horários. Isso significa possivelmente mudar o como você povoa o seu html

Comment: Ok, talvez não seja mais fácil, mas isso fornece mais semântica e estrutura sintática para se trabalhar; eu creio que é sempre melhor trabalhar num ambiente de semântica completa, por isso que para mim seria mais fácil

Comment: Sei não, sera que não da pra trabalhar com `radio button`?